# tcsh shell prompt to show unfinished jobs count

Tags: linux, prompt, tcsh

How do I make my tcsh shell prompt to show unfinished background jobs? I understand `%j` will tell me unfinished job number count but prompt goes stale if I keep it idle. Ideally, I would like prompt to get updated automatically. Basically, I want to avoid keep typing bjobs commands to check if all the jobs I submitted are completed.

Answer (score 1):

```
set prompt = "%j %# "
```

This would set the prompt to the current number of background jobs, followed by `>` or `#` for root (unless `promptchars` has been changed from the default).

Testing it:

```
> set prompt = "%j %# "
0 >
```

Then start a couple of background jobs:

```
0 > ls &
[1] 82556
1 > ls &
[2] 99869
[1]    Done                          ls
2 >
[2]    Done                          ls
2 >
2 >
2 >
2 >
2 >
2 >
2 >
```

As you see, the job count in the prompt is not updated when you just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  It *will* be updated once you enter a new command though:

```
2 > ls
0 >
0 >
```

---

You mentioned `bjobs`. This is an LFS command and not related to `tcsh` at all.  Please update the question with further information if this was intentional or not.